# svg bbox() always returns a value where x and y are 0 when they shouldn't be

Tags: javascript, html, svg, svg.js

I'm using SVG.js to draw shapes. One of the shapes needs to be a circle with a radius line so so get that behavior, I'm using an ellipse and a line inside of a "g" element.

The trouble is, whenever I reference that g element and try to get the bbox, I always get a value like this:

```
{
 x: 0, 
 y: 0, 
 width: widthOfBox, 
 height: heightOfBox, 
 cx: widthOfBox/2, 
 cy: heightOfBox/2
}
```

x and y should NOT be 0.

Below is the element in question that is clearly not at (0,0) but seems to be reporting that it is.

```
<g id="MLG1008" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" fill="#000000" transform="translate(100 200)" width="993.3559281546569" height="993.3559281546569" x="12.963409423828125" y="-290.0365905761719">
    <ellipse id="MLEllipse1009" rx="496.67796407732845" ry="496.67796407732845" cx="496.67796407732845" cy="496.67796407732845" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2"></ellipse>
    <line id="MLLine1010" x1="496.67796407732845" y1="496.67796407732845" x2="801.6779640773284" y2="888.6779640773284" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2"></line>
</g>
```

Is there a way to define the values that bbox should have? Or a way to set the values that bbox() looks at?

Answer (score 2):

From [W3 specs on getBBox](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#__svg__SVGLocatable__getBBox)

> [SVGRect](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#InterfaceSVGRect) getBBox()
>       Returns the tight bounding box in current user space (i.e., after application of the ‘[transform](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#TransformAttribute)’ attribute, if any) on the geometry of all **contained graphics elements**, exclusive of stroking, clipping, masking and filter effects). [...]

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

As you can see in this definition, the SVGRect returned by `getBBox` is calculated against the ***contained graphics elements***, this means that the translation you applied on your `<g>` element will not be taken into account in this SVGRect, since the transformation is applied on the element itself, and not on its graphic content.

You could get these `x` and `y` values by wrapping your transformed `<g>` element inside an other `<g>` from which you would call its `getBBox()` method,

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("wrapper").getBBox());
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1500 1500" width="300" height="300">
  <g id="wrapper">
    <g id="MLG1008" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" fill="#000000" transform="translate(100 200)">
        <ellipse id="MLEllipse1009" rx="496.67796407732845" ry="496.67796407732845" cx="496.67796407732845" cy="496.67796407732845" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2"></ellipse>
        <line id="MLLine1010" x1="496.67796407732845" y1="496.67796407732845" x2="801.6779640773284" y2="888.6779640773284" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2"></line>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

or even on the parent `<svg>` if all its graphic elements are inside this `<g>`:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("svg").getBBox());
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1500 1500" width="300" height="300">
  <g id="MLG1008" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" fill="#000000" transform="translate(100 200)">
      <ellipse id="MLEllipse1009" rx="496.67796407732845" ry="496.67796407732845" cx="496.67796407732845" cy="496.67796407732845" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2"></ellipse>
      <line id="MLLine1010" x1="496.67796407732845" y1="496.67796407732845" x2="801.6779640773284" y2="888.6779640773284" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2"></line>
  </g>
</svg>
```

---

Also, even if unrelated with your issue, note that `<g>` element doesn't have `width`, `height`, `x` nor `y` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Because your `<g>` positioned relative to `<svg>`. You need to use `transform="translate(x, y)"` to change the element position.

Comment: Better say: `<g>` has no x and y attributes.

Comment: @ccprog it does. They're at the end.

Comment: @itcropper misunderstanding - x and y are not valid attributes for `<g>`. In other words: you cannot absolutely position a `<g>`, but only transform its contents.

Comment: I still must be doing something wrong here. Using transform="translate(x y)" works at move <g>, but still seems to have no effect on the bounding box of <g>

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar case:

1. you add setTimerOut is working.
   2: I remove getBBox() and replace
   getAttribute("x") // x,y,width,height